# The Armature Is Hidden

Tags: bones

I literally can't unhide it.  I don't know why it won't let me. I've tried ALT+H, but that won't work, I've tried selecting it, and a few other things.  If you know what to do, please let me know.

P.S. I also can't edit it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: If your armature is hidden, I guess you're selecting it in the _Outliner_? Is it inside a collection which is hidden?

Answer (score 1):

You might have accidentally moved it to a different Skeleton Layer.
e.g.

## Before

[image]

## After

[image]

---

Notice that while the armature has both 3D Viewport + Render visibility enabled in the Outliner Editor, it's still hidden if on a different Skeleton Layer.